# Landsat8 DN to TOA Reflectance (minus values)

Tags: remote-sensing, envi, landsat-8, toa-calibration, atmospheric-correction

I'm learning how to perform atmospheric correction manually, hence not using the automated methods available in ENVI

metadata (band 1) for my Landsat 8 scene is as follows;

RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_1 = 1.2344E-02

RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_1 = -61.72016

REFLECTANCE_MULT_BAND_1 = 2.0000E-05

REFLECTANCE_ADD_BAND_1 = -0.100000

SUN_ELEVATION = 48.12237303

So when I use band math to calculate TOA Radiance I type in this:

(0.012344*B1)-61.72016

And it yields a spectral statistics that look kind-of right
[image: SpectralStats]

When I use any of the following band math formulae;

TOA Reflectance (excluding sun elevation adjustment)

(B1*0.00002)-0.1

TOA Reflectance (including sun elevation adjustment)

((B1*0.00002)-0.1)/0.74457226676389733207607359928648

Or calculate straight from the raw DN to TOA Reflectance (including sun elevation adjustment)

((((0.012344*B1)-61.72016)*0.00002)-0.1)/0.74457226676389733207607359928648

I end up with something like this:

[image: TOA Reflectance]

which looks incorrect.

I've googled and either my search terms are rubbish or no one uses manual band math to do this.

[EDIT]

Mikkel's answer below with the revised band math calculation (omitting the intermediate steps) yielded the following statistics:

[image]

which look somewhat more realistic.

Wondering if i should add 13.4305 to each band, or ignore the negative minimum?

[END EDIT]

[EDIT #2]

Mikkel was spot on again, in suggesting that the -13.4305 values were isolated to the "no data" areas around the image;

[image]

as you can see, isolated only to the northern edge of the scene.

[END EDIT #2]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One flaw in your approach. You don't need to go through DN to radiance.
You can go straight to the DN to reflectance.
Just stick to `((B1*0.00002)-0.1)/0.74457226676389733207607359928648`.

Comment: this worked pretty well! i suppose either it was never explained that TOA radiance / TOA reflectance excl. sun elevation weren't necessary steps in the correction sequence.

Comment: per the edited post above, is it necessary to add 13.4305 to each band to bring them up to min = 0, or is that unnecessary??

Comment: @kyuss , try checking where those -0.134305 are located. I suspect that it is the no-data areas around the edge of the image.

Comment: brilliant, i didn't even check anything but the southern borders where there werent negative values. thanks for all of your help.

Comment: @kyuss now the next step in your process is "simply" to do the atmospheric correction.

Comment: haha, yeah i don't think im using a physical model, just dark pix subtraction.

Comment: Just to clarify: performing ((B1*0.00002)-0.1) is essentially "going through radiance" [1](https://landsat.usgs.gov/using-usgs-landsat-8-product)

Comment: @unnic - ((B1*0.00002)-0.1) means that you skip radiance. It takes you straight from DN to reflectance.

Comment: @MikkelLydholmRasmussen yeah you are right. I confused some of the info in the link i posted yesterday. sorry and thanks for your comment

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good read on the physics of atmospheric correction, and might help with the issue... I'm a button pushing guy, I feel your pain, at least you can just click that beautiful QUAC or FLAASH button once you're outside of academia.

http://modis.gsfc.nasa.gov/data/atbd/atbd_mod08.pdf

Comment: thanks Steven. i have - as you've inferred - learned much during my study but that modis document may well help fill out my understanding gaps re: radiative transfer.