# Python - Calculating Burned Area Index results in empty plot

Tags: python, multi-band, vegetation-index, earthpy

I've followed [this tutorial](https://www.earthdatascience.org/courses/use-data-open-source-python/multispectral-remote-sensing/vegetation-indices-in-python/calculate-dNBR-Landsat-8/) to calculate the [dNBR Index](http://gsp.humboldt.edu/OLM/Courses/GSP_216_Online/lesson5-1/NBR.html), using the given sample `tif` files which contain a burned area. My results were as shown on the tutorial. So far so good.

Then I tried to calculate the [Burned Area Index (BAI)](http://space4water.org/taxonomy/term/1255) after making a few modifications on the above tutorial's code. The result is an empty plot.

This is my implementation:

(Note: The code downloads tif images from [here](https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pfigshare-u-files/10960109/coldspringsfire.zip))

```
from glob import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xarray as xr
import rioxarray as rxr
import earthpy.plot as ep
import earthpy as et
import os

def combine_tifs(tif_list):
    """A function that combines a list of tifs in the same CRS
    and of the same extent into an xarray object

    Parameters
    ----------
    tif_list : list
    A list of paths to the tif files that you wish to combine.

    Returns
    -------
    An xarray object with all of the tif files in the listmerged into
    a single object.

    """

    out_xr = []
    for i, tif_path in enumerate(tif_list):
    out_xr.append(rxr.open_rasterio(tif_path, masked=True).squeeze())
    out_xr[i]["band"] = i+1

    return xr.concat(out_xr, dim="band")

path_to_downloaded_data = et.data.get_data('cold-springs-fire', replace=True)

all_landsat_bands_path = glob(os.path.join(path_to_downloaded_data,
                                       "landsat_collect",
                                       "LC080340322016072301T1-SC20180214145802",
                                       "crop",
                                       "*band[1-7]*.tif"))

all_landsat_bands_path.sort()
all_bands = combine_tifs(all_landsat_bands_path)

red_square = (0.1 - all_bands[3]) * (0.1 - all_bands[3])
nir_square = (0.06 - all_bands[4]) * (0.06 - all_bands[4])
burned_area_index = 1 / (red_square + nir_square)

fig1, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 12))
fig1 = plt.gcf()
ep.plot_bands(burned_area_index,
          cmap='PiYG',
          scale=False,
          cbar=False,  # Change this to TRUE to display the color bar
          ax=ax,
          vmin=-1, vmax=1,
          title="BAI")
plt.show()
```

The values of the `burned_area_index` array are very low, in the magnitude of 10^-7.

My question is, if the formula is correct, what might be the problem that results in an empty plot?

Comment: Look at the range of the values in the data. You're using Level 1 data which is scaled DN. The formula you linked to requires reflectance (0.0 - 1.0). Either calculate TOA reflectance (https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/166072/2856) or download the surface reflectance product.

Comment: As user2856 pointed out, you need products with bands expressed in reflectance. With these changes, threshold value for discriminating burnt areas is > 89.